# PostgreSQL RPCs : allow required array parameters that will be processed in ANY/IN keywords to be null/empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgrest

I have a PostgreSQL RPC that aims to select filtered rows of a view.
This RPC requires some parameters (name_article, catg_article, color_article, etc).
Most of these parameters are int[]/bigint[] because I want the user to be able to request "all blue articles or all red articles, etc" but I want the user to be able to post empty parameters as well, and that the request considers he doesn't care about which color or category so it will return all possibilities.

The problem is that from what I saw after many topics on Internet, the `ANY ()` or `IN ()` can't be empty, which I'd like to allow it otherwise my filters system would have to manage all possibilities and I really don't want to cry.

This is what I've readen on Internet to try ( ***param is null or in()/any()*** ) but it doesn't work, not returning any article (the first where is fine, also don't pay attention to the cast thing, it's just that catg_and_type is json so I have to say id_catgarticle from this json is a bigint so it works fine) :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dev.get_all_articles
WHERE get_all_articles.lib_article ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
AND ($2 is null or CAST(get_all_articles.catg_et_type->>'id_catgarticle' AS BIGINT) = any ($2));
```

Do you have any idea how I could allow empty arrays that will be processed with IN/ANY commands ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the function signature and the PostgREST request you are making? The whole `CREATE FUNCTION` statement would help too. Also try adding a default value to your optional parameters like `my_function(param_a default NULL)`, maybe the request is forcing to send an empty array which is not `NULL`.

Comment: @LaurenceIsla Hey, sorry for answering late, been kind of busy. I've already tried the `(param default NULL)` which doesn't work for some reason... I've finally found a correct solution, it was mostly a syntax thing. The syntax I had to write in the `AND` was `AND ($2 IS null OR $2 = '{}' OR CAST ....` because when passing an array into a PostgREST endpoint, it wants the syntax to be `/rpc/endpoint?param={1,2,3}` and so this is why the `ÒR $2 = '{}'` in SQL. So now my request allows PostgREST to send empty array and returns all rows as I wanted. Problem solved. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, as mentionned into my answer to @LaurenceIsla's answer to the topic.

When having to send an array parameter into a PostgREST API endpoint, the syntax is like this : `/rpc/endpoint?param={1,2,3}`. So in order to make the request understand an empty param in URL (`endpoint?param={}`), I had to say, in the WHERE clause this : `OR $2 = '{}'`. That's all. Kind of tricky syntax when you don't know it.